# Block an account in a permissioned blockchain environment

Tags: accounts, permissioned-chain

We are developing a permissioned blockchain environment with Ethermint.
Companies have to apply to join the blockchain environment, we create and give them their Ethereum account.

One of the main concerns is how to remove or block an account from the environment if it turns out this company isn't playing nice.

We thought of flagging the organization contract, or destroying it, but then you would have to put a modifier on almost every method AND they can still commit transactions with their Ethereum account.

I'm not sure it is even possible to block such account from a permissioned blockchain environment, because, well, that is what decentralisation is about obviously :-) 
But maybe there is a work around, or a "pattern" to use here.

Answer (score 1):

Very easy to do actually.

This function is a single entry to modify balances on Ethereum (`core/state_transition.go`):

```
// TransitionDb will transition the state by applying the current message and
// returning the result including the the used gas. It returns an error if it
// failed. An error indicates a consensus issue.
func (st *StateTransition) TransitionDb() (ret []byte, usedGas uint64, failed bool, err error) {
    if err = st.preCheck(); err != nil {
        return
    }
    msg := st.msg
    sender := vm.AccountRef(msg.From())
    homestead := st.evm.ChainConfig().IsHomestead(st.evm.BlockNumber)
    contractCreation := msg.To() == nil

    // Pay intrinsic gas
    gas, err := IntrinsicGas(st.data, contractCreation, homestead)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, 0, false, err
    }
    if err = st.useGas(gas); err != nil {
        return nil, 0, false, err
    }

    var (
        evm = st.evm
        // vm errors do not effect consensus and are therefor
        // not assigned to err, except for insufficient balance
        // error.
        vmerr error
    )
    if contractCreation {
        ret, _, st.gas, vmerr = evm.Create(sender, st.data, st.gas, st.value)
    } else {
        // Increment the nonce for the next transaction
        st.state.SetNonce(msg.From(), st.state.GetNonce(sender.Address())+1)
        ret, st.gas, vmerr = evm.Call(sender, st.to(), st.data, st.gas, st.value)
    }
    if vmerr != nil {
        log.Debug("VM returned with error", "err", vmerr)
        // The only possible consensus-error would be if there wasn't
        // sufficient balance to make the transfer happen. The first
        // balance transfer may never fail.
        if vmerr == vm.ErrInsufficientBalance {
            return nil, 0, false, vmerr
        }
    }
    st.refundGas()
    st.state.AddBalance(st.evm.Coinbase, new(big.Int).Mul(new(big.Int).SetUint64(st.gasUsed()), st.gasPrice))

    return ret, st.gasUsed(), vmerr != nil, err
}
```

You have to do something like this:

```
func (st *StateTransition) TransitionDb() (ret []byte, usedGas uint64, failed bool, err error) {
    if err = st.preCheck(); err != nil {
        return
    }
    msg := st.msg
    sender := vm.AccountRef(msg.From())
    homestead := st.evm.ChainConfig().IsHomestead(st.evm.BlockNumber)
    contractCreation := msg.To() == nil

    // here is where your custom code goes:

    errAccessDenied:=errors.New("Company isn't playing nice")
    blacklisted_address,exists:=blacklists[sender]
    if exists {
        return ret,0,false, errAccessDenied
    }
    blacklisted_address,exists=blaclists[st.to()]
    if exists {
        return ret,0,false,errAccessDenied
    }
    // here is where your custom code ends   

    // Pay intrinsic gas
    gas, err := IntrinsicGas(st.data, contractCreation, homestead)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, 0, false, err
    }
    if err = st.useGas(gas); err != nil {
        return nil, 0, false, err
    }

    var (
        evm = st.evm
        // vm errors do not effect consensus and are therefor
        // not assigned to err, except for insufficient balance
        // error.
        vmerr error
    )

    if contractCreation {
        ret, _, st.gas, vmerr = evm.Create(sender, st.data, st.gas, st.value)
    } else {
        // Increment the nonce for the next transaction
        st.state.SetNonce(msg.From(), st.state.GetNonce(sender.Address())+1)
        ret, st.gas, vmerr = evm.Call(sender, st.to(), st.data, st.gas, st.value)
    }
    if vmerr != nil {
        log.Debug("VM returned with error", "err", vmerr)
        // The only possible consensus-error would be if there wasn't
        // sufficient balance to make the transfer happen. The first
        // balance transfer may never fail.
        if vmerr == vm.ErrInsufficientBalance {
            return nil, 0, false, vmerr
        }
    }
    st.refundGas()
    st.state.AddBalance(st.evm.Coinbase, new(big.Int).Mul(new(big.Int).SetUint64(st.gasUsed()), st.gasPrice))

    return ret, st.gasUsed(), vmerr != nil, err
}
```

Of course, it's not a tested code but you get an idea. Also you have to include the functionality to distribute the list of companies that do not play nice among nodes. The hash of the black list must be included int the block header (types.Header)